# RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (222) must match the size of tensor b (168) at non-singleton dimension 3

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to train a CNN-ViT hybrid model on a custom dataset (using the instructions found [here](https://github.com/keyu-tian/SparK/tree/main/pretrain) ). I think I am correctly pushing the images through the neural network, but I keep running into this issue. I no longer have an idea of what to make of this error. Initially I thought it had to do with the way I was building my custom dataset, but I rewrote it in a different way in an attempt to subvert the error, yet I still ran into it.

I have seen answers and comments about similar errors posted on here but seemingly none of them match what I am seeing.

The images I am using are all 224x224. I have confirmed this by checking the size and shape of every image.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 193, in <module>
    main_pt()
  File "main.py", line 103, in main_pt
    stats = pre_train_one_ep(ep, args, tb_lg, itrt_train, iters_train, model, optimizer)
  File "main.py", line 159, in pre_train_one_ep
    loss = model(inp, active_b1ff=None, vis=False)
  File "/global/common/software/nersc/shasta2105/pytorch/1.9.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 36, in forward
    return self.module(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/global/common/software/nersc/shasta2105/pytorch/1.9.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/global/cfs/cdirs/dune/www/data/2x2/simulation/silentc_work/SparK/SparK/SparK/pretrain/spark.py", line 96, in forward
    fea_bcffs: List[torch.Tensor] = self.sparse_encoder(masked_bchw)
  File "/global/common/software/nersc/shasta2105/pytorch/1.9.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/global/cfs/cdirs/dune/www/data/2x2/simulation/silentc_work/SparK/SparK/SparK/pretrain/encoder.py", line 209, in forward
    return self.sp_cnn(x, hierarchical=True)
  File "/global/common/software/nersc/shasta2105/pytorch/1.9.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/global/cfs/cdirs/dune/www/data/2x2/simulation/silentc_work/SparK/SparK/SparK/pretrain/models/custom.py", line 42, in forward
    x = self.conv1(inp_bchw)
  File "/global/common/software/nersc/shasta2105/pytorch/1.9.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/global/cfs/cdirs/dune/www/data/2x2/simulation/silentc_work/SparK/SparK/SparK/pretrain/encoder.py", line 23, in sp_conv_forward
    x *= _get_active_ex_or_ii(H=x.shape[2], W=x.shape[3], returning_active_ex=True)    # (BCHW) *= (B1HW), mask the output of conv
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (222) must match the size of tensor b (168) at non-singleton dimension 3
```

Here is my dataset loader code:

```
import os
from typing import Any, Callable, Optional, Tuple

import PIL.Image as PImage
from timm.data import IMAGENET_DEFAULT_MEAN, IMAGENET_DEFAULT_STD
from torchvision.datasets.folder import DatasetFolder, IMG_EXTENSIONS
from torchvision.transforms import transforms
from torch.utils.data import Dataset

#print(IMAGENET_DEFAULT_MEAN, IMAGENET_DEFAULT_STD)

try:
    from torchvision.transforms import InterpolationMode
    interpolation = InterpolationMode.BICUBIC
except:
    import PIL
    interpolation = PIL.Image.BICUBIC


def pil_loader(path):
    # open path as file to avoid ResourceWarning (https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/835)
    with open(path, 'rb') as f: img: PImage.Image = PImage.open(f).convert('L')
    return img



import os
from PIL import Image
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torchvision import transforms

class YourcnnDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data_path, input_size, transform=None):
        self.data_path = data_path
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.transform = transform
        self.images = self._load_images()

    def _load_images(self):
        # Load images from the data_path directory
        image_list = []
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self.data_path):
            for file in files:
                if file.endswith(".jpg") or file.endswith(".png"):
                    image_list.append(os.path.join(root, file))
        return image_list

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.images)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img_path = self.images[idx]
        image = Image.open(img_path).convert("L")

        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
        image = transforms.ToTensor()(image)

        return image

def build_your_dataset(data_path, input_size, batch_size):
    # Define your transformation for the dataset
    your_transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
        transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize(mean=(0.5), std=(0.5)),]) #transforms.Resize((224, 224)), transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(), transforms.Normalize(mean=(0.5), std=(0.5)),   https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/9446

    # Create an instance of your custom dataset
    your_dataset = YourCustomDataset(data_path, input_size, transform=your_transform)

    # Data loader to handle batching
    data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(your_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

    return data_loader
```

Here is the model architecture:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from typing import List
from timm.models.registry import register_model


class YourConvNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes=0, global_pool=''):
        super(YourConvNet, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3, stride=1)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.maxpool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, padding=0)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3, stride=1)
        self.maxpool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, padding=0)

    def get_downsample_ratio(self) -> int:
        # Define the downsampling ratio
        return 4  # Update this based on your actual architecture

    def get_feature_map_channels(self) -> List[int]:
        # Define the number of channels of each feature map
        return [32, 64]  # for conv1 and conv2

    def forward(self, inp_bchw: torch.Tensor, hierarchical=False):
        """
        The forward with `hierarchical=True` would ONLY be used in `SparseEncoder.forward` (see `pretrain/encoder.py`).

        :param inp_bchw: input image tensor, shape: (batch_size, channels, height, width).
        :param hierarchical: return the logits (not hierarchical), or the feature maps (hierarchical).
        :return:
            - hierarchical == False: return the logits of the classification task, shape: (batch_size, num_classes).
            - hierarchical == True: return a list of all feature maps, which should have the same length as the return value of `get_feature_map_channels`.
              E.g., for the provided ConvNet, it should return a list [1st_feat_map, 2nd_feat_map].
                    for an input size, the shapes could be [(B, 32, 56, 56), (B, 64, 28, 28)] based on provided architecture.
        """
        x = self.conv1(inp_bchw)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.maxpool1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.maxpool2(x)

        # Depending on the hierarchical flag, return feature maps or logits
        if hierarchical:
            # Return feature maps
            #return [(1, 64, 12, 12)]  # Update this based on your actual architecture
            return [(1, 64, 54, 54)]
        else:
            # Perform further operations for classification logits, if needed
            # Example: Flatten x and add fully connected layers
            return x


@register_model
def your_convnet_small(pretrained=False, **kwargs):
    return YourConvNet(**kwargs)

@register_model
def your_cnn(pretrained=False, **kwargs):
    return YourConvNet(**kwargs)


@torch.no_grad()
def convnet_test():
    from timm.models import create_model
    cnn = create_model('your_convnet_small')
    print('get_downsample_ratio:', cnn.get_downsample_ratio())
    print('get_feature_map_channels:', cnn.get_feature_map_channels())


    downsample_ratio = cnn.get_downsample_ratio()
    feature_map_channels = cnn.get_feature_map_channels()
    
    # check the forward function
    B, C, H, W = 100, 1, 224, 224
    inp = torch.rand(B, C, H, W)
    feats = cnn(inp, hierarchical=True)
    assert isinstance(feats, list)
    assert len(feats) == len(feature_map_channels)
    print([tuple(t.shape) for t in feats])
    
    # check the downsample ratio
    feats = cnn(inp, hierarchical=True)
    assert feats[-1].shape[-2] == H // downsample_ratio
    assert feats[-1].shape[-1] == W // downsample_ratio
    
    # check the channel number
    for feat, ch in zip(feats, feature_map_channels):
        assert feat.ndim == 4
        assert feat.shape[1] == ch


if __name__ == '__main__':
    convnet_test()
```

I am able to pass through the cnn model like so:

```
import torch
from custom import YourConvNet  # Replace 'YourConvNet_module_file' with your actual module file name

# Instantiate your YourConvNet model
model = YourConvNet()

# Define sample input data
sample_input = torch.randn(1, 1, 224, 224)  # Assuming input shape (batch_size, channels, height, width)

# Perform a forward pass to get the output feature maps
with torch.no_grad():
    feature_maps = model(sample_input, hierarchical=True)

# Print the shapes of the output feature maps
for i, fmap in enumerate(feature_maps):
    print(i, fmap)
```

Comment: Can you see if you can run a random input through the model? This will help identify if the issue is in the model code, training code, or data processing code.

Comment: I am able to pass through the cnn model. I updated the question to show this. I am not sure how to test the other codes using an input.

Comment: if I'm reading this right, you're saying an input of shape `(100, 1, 224, 224)` works. so check the shape of your batches to see if it's different. You might be missing the channel axis.

Comment: I was hoping that would fix my issue. The input batch shape is ```torch.Size([100, 1, 224, 224])```. Hmm I cant think of where things could be failing.

Comment: so it looks like this function:
```
def _get_active_ex_or_ii(H, W, returning_active_ex=True):
    h_repeat, w_repeat = H // _cur_active.shape[-2], W // _cur_active.shape[-1]
    active_ex = _cur_active.repeat_interleave(h_repeat, dim=2).repeat_interleave(w_repeat, dim=3)
    return active_ex if returning_active_ex else active_ex.squeeze(1).nonzero(as_tuple=True)  # ii: bi, hi, wi 
```
returns an abject of shape ```torch.Size([32, 1, 168, 168])``` instead of ```torch.Size([32, 1, 224, 224])```
I am not sure why this is. Sorry for the bad formatting

Comment: So I think I solved it by changing the way the CNN was defined so that upsampling and downsampling worked as they are supposed to. I will post an answer as soon as the system lets me.